# PBEKeySpec C++ analog

Tags: java, c++, cryptography, aes

I've never used C++ before, but now i need to migrate this function to C++:

```
public static byte[] getSafeKey(String key, byte[] initVector) {
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), initVector,
            ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
    try {
        keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    return skey.getEncoded();
}
```

So far I found one PBEKeySpec analog: http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/doxygen/c++/classbeecrypt_1_1crypto_1_1spec_1_1PBEKeySpec.html

But even then I have no idea what to do with keyFactory and farther.

Is there a simple way to write it in C++?

Comment: I removed the Crypto++ tag. You should add the tag when you are using the technology; and not for "what should I do and how should I do it?" questions.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Won't do it again. Actually I use it in project, thats why I added tag.

Answer (score 1):

For managed code you may be able to use the badly named [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) . [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) defines PKCS#5: Password-Based Encryption. This version includes the PBKDF2 password hash (or password based key derivation function if you must).

For non-managed code there seems to be [an implementation of PBKDF2 in Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k_c_s5___p_b_k_d_f2___h_m_a_c.html). Note that the hash in the Java version is used within the HMAC construction as well. [Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1PKCS5__PBKDF2.html) is also an option.

Beware that the Java version uses the lowest 8 bits of `char` values of the password directly. So it may well be incompatible with other implementations for non-ASCII characters.